# Django migrations: TypeError: db_type() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

So I am trying to integrate my legacy postgresql to django. I have successfully created my models following this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/
However when I add something to my models and try to migrate I get the following error:

```
> Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, pSQL, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying pSQL.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 246, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 136, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 647, in db_parameters
    type_string = self.db_type(connection)
TypeError: db_type() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The initial migration file:
**https://gist.github.com/eayantsquare/c0d7b31268b298490a0e77f566746f8d**

Edit:
 The problem is gone but i am not sure what fixed it. I basically deleted migrtions and tried from the start. On the way, it was fixed somehow. I am going to leave question unanswered so maybe someone will have a more compact answer.

Comment: Take connection out of the db_type call

Comment: this isn't my code, this is build in django code. You cannot be suggesting me to actually change the library?

Comment: Please show the migration `pSQL/0001_initial.py` that is failing.

Comment: Then that arg seems to be added dynamically so we need to see the code that creates this trace back

Comment: @jacobIRR what do you mean exactly? added it as github gist becuase it is a large file and updated my question

Comment: try to delete migrations folder and then migrate it or use fake migrations command